# Why would I want to use a static library?

Tags: xcode, ios

I understand for non-iOS targets, using shared libraries can lead to lower memory usage, and also that some companies distribute a library and headers (like [Superpin](http://getsuperpin.com/)) and a static library allows them to not distribute the source of their product. But outside of those, what are the reasons you'd want to use a static library? I use git for all of my projects, and I usually add external libraries (open source ones) as a submodule. This means they  take up disk space locally, but they do not clutter up the repo. Also since iOS doesn't support shared libraries, the benefits of building libraries to promote code reuse seems diminished.

Basically, is there any reason outside of selling closed source libraries that it makes sense to build/use static libraries for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

organization, reuse, and easy integration into other programs.

if you have a library which is used by multiple apps or targets multiple platforms, then you will have to maintain the build for each app. with a library, you let the library maintainer set up the build correctly, then you just link to the result (if it's developed internally, then you'll want to add it as a dependency too).

it's like DRY, but for projects.

libraries become more useful as projects become more complex. you should try to identify what programs (functions, class hierarchies, etc) are reusable outside of your app's context, and put it in a library for easy reuse - like pattern recognition.

once your codebase has hundreds or thousands of files, you will want to minimize what you use, and you will not want to maintain the dependencies manually for each project.

Answer (score 0):

Static libraries allow you to have truly standalone executables.  Since all library code is actually, physically present in the executable, you don't have to worry about the exec failing to run because there's a too-old version of some library, or a too-new one, or it's completely missing, etc.  And you don't have to worry about your app suddenly breaking because some library got replaced.  It cuts down on dependencies and lets your app be more encapsulated.

Comment: Your answer is correct in general, but not appropriate for iOS, because iOS doesn't support third party dynamic libraries. That is, the dev tools don't support building dynamic libraries.

Answer (score 0):

> Also since iOS doesn't support shared
>   libraries, the benefits of building
>   libraries to promote code reuse seems
>   diminished.

There's no reason you can't build your own static library to use across multiple projects.
Other than for that purpose and the ones you mentioned I don't think there's much else.

Comment: The main benefit would seem to be for very large subprojects that you would share across parent projects, so that the large project can be build only once?