# Do I need a "cocos2d libraries" target in an xcode project?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5, target

I have been building a project based upon the book "Learning Cocos2D". When I started this project, the latest cocos2d-iphone version was 1.0.1. Since then, the latest version is 2.0. I decided to upgrade because I was getting a compiler error "Variable length of array of non-POD element type b2Vec2" and the [suggestion](http://cartoonsmartblog.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/upgrading-xcode-from-4-1-to-4-2-and-updating-to-the-latest-cocos2d/) to fix this included upgrading. This pointed to a [tutorial](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/05/update-cocos2d-iphone-existing-project/) on upgrading. In this tutorial, step #4 is about re-adding your library folders and says "Make sure that only the cocos2d libraries target is selected to avoid any build errors". Unfortunately, I do not have a "cocos2d libraries" target. I then went back into the second chapter of "Learning Cocos2D" and I noticed that the book shows the existence of this target on p. 25. However, it was not created when I followed book's instructions to create the project.

Do I need to have this cocos2d libraries target? If so, is it too late to create it? Up until this point, I never had a problem without it, but now I am concerned about continuing with this upgrade. If I need it, how do I create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the cocos2d library target is explained in both the book and tutorial. Maybe start from scratch and try again, it certainly works.

Alternatively you can follow [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23854/arc-and-cocos2d-v2-x) which doesn't use a static library.

It doesn't make much of a difference for an individual project. Using a static library is just a cleaner approach, [keeping things separate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113838/why-would-i-want-to-use-a-static-library). One benefit is that you could have a workspace with multiple projects that all link to the cocos2d library, so you only need to build the cocos2d code once and the other projects can use the cocos2d library without having to recompile its source code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the cocos2d library target. I went ahead and continued the upgrade to cocos2d-iphone version 2.0 without a static library. Unfortunately, this resulted in a number of compiler errors. I was working through the Box2D tutorial in chapter 10 of "Learning Cocos2D". Example errors occurred in PuzzleLayer.mm with b2World constructor and SetAsEdge. Would you advise against upgrading to version 2.0 while I am working through this tutorial? Alternatively, do you have a website that corrects this Box2D tutorial to be compatible with version 2.0 of cocos2D?

Comment: It appears to have been a major mistake to upgrade to cocos2d v2.0 while using the "Learning Cocos2D" book. It has taken a tremendous effort to upgrade the SpaceViking enemy and game objects to be compatible. I also tried starting from scratch to see if the cocos2d library target is created, but it does not get created using the instructions in the book. However, I did find your web page link that shows how to add the cocos2d library target as it relates to ARC: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/.